# Complexed Query - Sort by newest with average of 2 other values

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to sort by date and average likes/dislikes.

**Picture #1**: 5 likes, 2 dislikes, created 1 week ago

**Picture #2**: 5 likes, 2 dislikes, created a minute ago

Example: If **picture #1** has 5 likes and 2 dislikes but is created 1 week ago, then this wouldn't show up on the first row because **picture #2** has the same amount of likes and dislikes but is newer than **picture #1**.

This is what I have so far:

```
SELECT * FROM `pictures` GROUP BY id ORDER BY avg(likes/dislikes) desc LIMIT 10
```

**Desired Result:**

```
Row 1 --> Picture #2
Row 2 --> Picture #1
```

I greatly appreciate any answers.

Comment: Consider providing some sample data and a desired result. You might want to lower the target to say 5 likes and 2 dislikes for the sake of simplicity

Comment: So you want to order pictures by AVG of likes/dislikes BUT if they're equal you want to order by date, right?

Comment: Not quite... I want to basically have the date as a value.. If the post is like 2 weeks old, then it'll show up at the end of the table.

Comment: Does any of this make sense? It's really hard to explain

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `order by` clause can be use with more than one column.

Try this;  `ORDER BY avg(likes/dislikes) desc, created desc` (assuming `created` is the name of your date column)

It first orders the result set by the average of likes/dislikes , then it orders lines with sames avg, by created dates.

@update [Sqlfiddle example](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/81d82/4)

@update2 
Case expression can be use in the order by clause, see an example:
[Sqlfiddle example with case in order by](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/640d9/1)

Comment: See my update, I add an example, it works as intended. What's wrong ?

Comment: Works fine via Sqlfiddle.. But please read my latest comment above, can this query achieve what I want?

Comment: Actually, looks like your answer works just fine.. Didn't really expect it to be so simple though

Comment: @FilipBusic, I update my answer and add an other example wich order your data based on the time (1 minute is priority) and then with the average and crated date, you can now adjust the interval you need

Comment: So if I change second to day, does that mean that day is the priority?

Comment: YES, The case in the order by clause means: if the created date is newest than the now() - X ( second,minutes,days..) it will be displays in priority ( value 0 with ASC), then the others sort criterias applies.